# Get all records from collection with all refrences in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I'm currently blocked because I can't get all records from a collection with **references** values.

I would like to get all records from collection `events` (it works) but when I wanna merge the `category` information associated with `categoryId` my code doesn't work anymore.

**Events collection**
[image]

**Categories collection**
[image]

```js
export const getEventsRequest = async () => {
  const output = [];
  const data = await firebase.firestore().collection('events').get();

  data.forEach(async (doc) => {
    const {
      name,
      address,
      city,
      duration,
      level,
      startDate,
      maxPeople,
      categoryId,
    } = doc.data();

    const { name: categoryName, color } = (
      await firebase.firestore().collection('categories').doc(categoryId).get()
    ).data();

    output.push({
      name,
      address,
      city,
      duration,
      level,
      startDate,
      maxPeople,
      category: { name: categoryName, color },
    });
  });

  return output;
};
```

**Example testing in a React Native project**

```js
  const [events, setEvents] = useState([]);
  const [isEventsLoading, setIsEventsLoading] = useState(false);

  const getEvents = async () => {
    setEvents([]);
    setIsEventsLoading(true);

    try {
      const evts = await getEventsRequest();
      setEvents(evts);
      setIsEventsLoading(false);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getEvents();
  }, []);

  console.log('events', events);
```

**Output**

```
events Array []
```

**Expected**

```
events Array [
  {
    name : "blabla",
    address: "blabla",
    city: "blabla",
    duration: 60,
    level: "hard",
    startDate: "13/04/2021",
    maxPeople: 7,
    category: {
      name: "Football",
      color: "#fff"
    },
  },
  // ...
]
```

I don't know if there is a simpler method to retrieve this kind of data (for example there is `populate` method on mongo DB).

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`CollectionReference#get`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get), it returns a `Promise` containing a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) object. The [`forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) method on this class is not `Promise`/`async`-compatible which is why your code stops working as you expect.

What you can do, is use `QuerySnapshot#docs` to get an array of the documents in the collection, then create a `Promise`-returning function that processes each document and then use it with `Promise.all` to return the array of processed documents.

In it's simplest form, it would look like this:

```
async function getDocuments() {
  const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection("someCollection")
    .get();

  const promiseArray = querySnapshot.docs
    .map(async (doc) => {
      /* do some async work */
      return doc.data();
    });

  return Promise.all(promiseArray);
}
```

Applying it to your code gives:

```
export const getEventsRequest = async () => {
  const querySnapshot = await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('events')
    .get();

  const dataPromiseArray = querySnapshot.docs
    .map(async (doc) => {
      const {
        name,
        address,
        city,
        duration,
        level,
        startDate,
        maxPeople,
        categoryId,
      } = doc.data();

      const { name: categoryName, color } = (
        await firebase.firestore().collection('categories').doc(categoryId).get()
      ).data();

      return {
        name,
        address,
        city,
        duration,
        level,
        startDate,
        maxPeople,
        category: { name: categoryName, color },
      };
    });

  // wait for each promise to complete, returning the output data array
  return Promise.all(dataPromiseArray);
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @samthecodingman, it works! I thought there was a easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: @ThomasLeNaour Note that this code will break if the category doesn't exist. You can also further optimize it by caching the category fetch promises.