# How i can avoid the loop on my querysnapshot.foreach?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My User has 2 teams :

- Danse
- Judo

On my subcollection `"membersList"` the team Danse had 1 friend request and Judo had none.

So I'm suppose to have just one request on my screen. But when I have 2 or more teams, the while continue to loop and the request appear with the numbers of team.

I think the problem is on my `querySnaphost.forEach` but on my console he return me the doc not empty (so the team danse ) and an other one with document not found.

```
let fetch = async () => {
    firestore()
      .collection("Teams")
      .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (querySnapshot.empty) {
          console.log("no documents found");
        } else {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            let Teams = doc._data;
            console.log(Teams);
            updateActivity((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);
            console.log(Activity);

            doc.ref
              .collection("membersList")
              .where("statut", "==", "en attente")
              .get()
              .then((querySnapshot) => {
                if (querySnapshot.empty) {
                  console.log("no documents found cc");
                } else {
                  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                    let members = doc._data;
                    console.log("aa", members);
                    updateMembersList((arr) => [...arr, members]);
                    console.log("cc", MembersList);
                  });
                }
              });
          });
        }
      });
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch();
  }, []);
```

Here is what is logged when `fetch()` is called:

```
{"Activity": "Danse", "Adress": "Plage", "City": "Nice", "Owner": true, "members": "3", "text": "bouh", "tokenTeam": "n5ounxsf2bq", "uid": "PTbEn2fba0QudXI8JE8RioQ9of53"}
[]
no documents found cc
```

Comment: Is `MembersList` meant to contain a list of all pending friend requests for a particular user? Similarly, is `Activity` meant to be an array containing each `Team` that the user owns?

Comment: yes, basically Memberslist is the subcollection of teams and each teams has his memberslist ! which needs to appear when the statut is "pending"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not name your function `fetch` as this is a [reserved global function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) which you should treat like `undefined` - don't assign anything to it. I recommend also using `const` over `let` where applicable.

**Note:** This answer makes use of the same strategy described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67078814/3068190).

```
const fetchMemberRequests = async () => {
  const userTeamsQuerySnapshot = await firestore()
    .collection("Teams")
    .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
    .get();

  if (userTeamsQuerySnapshot.empty) {
    console.log("User owns no teams.");

    // empty Activity & MembersLists
    updateActivity([]);
    updateMembersList([]);
    return;
  }
  
  // for each team, fetch the pending requests and return a { team, memberRequests } object
  const fetchMemberRequestsPromises = userTeamsQuerySnapshot.docs
    .map(async (teamDocSnapshot) => {
      const teamData = teamDocSnapshot.data();
      
      const memberRequestsQuerySnapshot = await teamDocSnapshot.ref
        .collection("membersList")
        .where("statut", "==", "en attente")
        .get();
        
      if (memberRequestsQuerySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log(`Activity ${teamData.Activity} has no pending requests.`);
        return {
          team: teamData,
          memberRequests: []
        }
      }
      
      const memberRequestsArray = memberRequestsQuerySnapshot.docs
        .map((memberRequestDocSnapshot) => memberRequestDocSnapshot.data());
        
      console.log(`Activity ${teamData.Activity} has ${memberRequestsArray.length} pending requests.`);
      return {
        team: teamData,
        memberRequests: memberRequestsArray
      }
    });
    
  const memberRequests = await Promise.all(fetchMemberRequestsPromises);
  
  // memberRequests is an array of { team: teamData, memberRequests: arrayOfMembers }
  // which could be used to show the requests in groups
  
  // these lines replicate your current code:
  const allTeams = [];
  const allMemberRequests = [];
  for (const request of memberRequests) {
    allTeams.push(request.team);
    allMemberRequests.push(...request.memberRequests); // note: spreads array
  }
  
  console.log(`User owns ${allTeams.length} teams, with a total of ${allMemberRequests.length} pending requests.`);
  
  // replace Activity and MembersList rather than append to them
  updateActivity(allTeams);
  updateMembersList(allMemberRequests);
}
```

Comment: Except `await` doesn't work inside `.map()` :/

Comment: @JeremyThille This code functions as intended. In this code, I pass an `async` function to `map`, of which `await` is part of that function. By using this `async` function, `map` will return the type `Promise<ResultType>[]` instead of the regular type `ResultType[]`. Just having an array of Promises will do nothing interesting on it's own, but the array can be passed along to `Promise.all`, `Promise.allSettled`, `Promise.any` or `Promise.race` where it can then be used with `await`. In the above code, the `Promise` array is passed to `Promise.all`.

Comment: Using `await` in this way allows all of the asynchronous calls to be run in parallel, whereas using `await` inside a for loop forces the calls to be sequential.

Comment: My bad, I read too fast. I missed the `Promise.all` part. Twice you corrected me today, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the variable you are looping in (querySnapshot and doc) inside the loop, so I think this is messing up everything. If you loop over querySnapshot, then you should not reuse querySnapshot again inside the loop.

Also, to avoid headaches and callback hells, use `await` instead of `.then( .then( .then( .then())))`. You can't use `await` inside of a method (.filter(), .map(), .forEach() etc) but you can use it inside a `for` loop :

```
let fetch = async () => {

    const querySnapshot = await firestore()
        .collection("Teams")
        .where("uid", "==", await AsyncStorage.getItem("userID"))
        .get();

    if (querySnapshot.empty) {
        console.log("no documents found");
        return;
    }

    for( let doc of querySnapshot.docs){

        let Teams = doc._data;
        console.log(Teams);
        updateActivity((arr) => [...arr, Teams]);
        console.log(Activity);

        let querySnapshot2 = await doc.ref
            .collection("membersList")
            .where("statut", "==", "en attente")
            .get();

        if (querySnapshot2.empty) {
            console.log("no documents found");
            continue;
        }

        for(let doc2 of querySnapshot2.docs){
            let members = doc2._data;
            console.log("aa", members);
            updateMembersList( arr => [...arr, members]);
            console.log("cc", MembersList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you !! but i have this error :( TypeError: Invalid attempt to iterate non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.

Comment: I have to admit I'm not familiar with Firebase or firestore. Not sure if the returned elements are iterable, maybe they need some kind of transformation to array, like `.toArray()` or something?

Comment: After some quick research, I found out that `querySnapshot.docs` should be iterated. Answer updated

Comment: Applied the missing `await` instructions to the two `get()` queries.

Comment: Oh that's right, I missed that. Thanks :)